# Horizontal Scroll View not working in react native

Tags: react-native, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

horizontal scroll view is not working in my react native app. Here is my code below:

```
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {loading ? (
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={COLORS.blue} />
      ) : (
        kioskData.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <View key={index} style={styles.container1}>
              <ScrollView
                horizontal={true}
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
                <>
                  <Text>{item.product_price}</Text>
                  <Text>{item.product_name}</Text>
                </>
              </ScrollView>
            </View>
          );
        })
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    color: COLORS.black,
    backgroundColor: COLORS.white,
  },
  container1: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Am not sure where I am going wrong. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the usage of `ScrollView` in the wrong area which is inside of the loop (`map`).

Instead of creating an independent `ScrollView` for each item in the list, We can wrap the List Text elements within one single `ScrollView` Component.

let's update the `ScrollView` component tree to fix up the issue,

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  {loading ? (
    <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={COLORS.blue} />
  ) : (
    <View style={styles.container1}>
      <ScrollView horizontal showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
        {kioskData.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <Fragment key={index}>
              <Text>{item.product_price}</Text>
              <Text>{item.product_name}</Text>
            </Fragment>
          );
        })}
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  )}
</View>
```

Additional Tip:

If the list is quite large and has some performance concerns you can go for [`FlatList`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist) component for the same UI implementation.

```
  const renderItem = ({item}) => (
    <>
      <Text>{item.product_price}</Text>
      <Text>{item.product_name}</Text>
    </>
  );

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {loading ? (
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={COLORS.blue} />
      ) : (
        <View style={styles.container1}>
          <FlatList
            data={kioskData}
            horizontal
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          />
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I tried the first solution and it worked. I will look into Flatlist as well.

Answer (score -1):

just used    `horizontal={true}`

```
 <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <ScrollView
      horizontal={true}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
      <Text>asdasdasd</Text>
      <Text>asdasdasd</Text>
      <Text>asdasdasd</Text>
      <Text>asdasdasd</Text>
      <Text>asdasdasd</Text>
      <Text>asdasdasd</Text>
      <Text>asdasdasd</Text>
      <Text>asdasdasd</Text>
      <Text>asdasdasd</Text>
      <Text>asdasdasd</Text>
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
```